# Why web servers are needed even for local web application

Tags: php, web

I'm searching for a means to overpass the need for a web server when using a local web application. Why aren't there browser extensions or special browsers to do so? It seems very easy to code to me. The browser or extension would call a php interpreter to compose web pages from php files. Local urls (file:///) would be used. No web service or port would be necessary. Is this just nonsense? Or am I the first person to think about this? In fact, this does already work with static html files.

First edit: I was looking for a server for testing purposes, being able to compose output from php files, without the need to communicate through network ports. Maybe I should have started from here, but Stackoverflow does not allow this kind of posts.

Comment: Who would do the apache's job? Like set global variables $_SERVER, $_GET, $_POST?

Comment: Easy ? really ! ... Jetbrains have been trying to provide a 'builtin' server with PhpStorm for a long time, and errr ... well it still sucks. And honestly, they are no slouches. Go right ahead and build one.

Comment: Then who would process user inputs, access computer resources, serve outputs?

Comment: I'm not trying to say that it is easy. I just want to know why it isn't. What kind of environment has Apache to set to make php work? Is that such a huge piece of information?

Comment: User inputs are client side so the browser would, access to computer resources and serving outputs would be accomplished by php.

Comment: Let's suppose this environment is really huge so I can't replicate that. Then Why Apache doesn't split this into two independent modules? The first to compound outputs, the second to listen to tcp ports and transmit the generated code? I need only the first one.

Comment: I'd suggest having a read about server stacks, HTTP, middleware etc and learn what they do and the point of each one in order to understand the why.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds nice, please go ahead and build that technology. I will also use it. But oh, for now that has nothing to do with SO.

> Why web servers are needed even for local web application

Because they are **web applications**. Technically you don't need a web server for local stuff if all your application code relies on client side programming. You can just go ahead open your html files in browser.

Browsers know how to interpret client side code already, so why re-invent the wheel? If you ever wish to write 1 line of **server side** code then obviously you'd need a web server at that point.

Comment: Because I want to use a web application locally in an environment where I 'm not allowd to start a web service for it. The web app isn't coded by me, so I can't just use client side scripting.

Comment: Then there is no other solution currently